# C# Write "Binary Tree" type object on file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binary-tree

Im trying to write all of these objects onto a file but I cant find a way to do it on a way the threads dont overwrite the file. The structure is pretty simple,every object of this type got some data and two objects of the same type as child and so on. I need to save some of the data stored on every object on a file data so I can read it later.

```
public class Hueco
{
    GameObject hueco;
    GameObject balda;
    Vector3 Centro;
    Hueco hueco1; 
    Hueco hueco2; 
    int division; 
    static List<float> listaYBaldas = new List<float>();
    static List<float> listaXBaldas = new List<float>();
    float aux1, aux2;
    public Hueco()
    {
        hueco = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        hueco.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }

//Constructor
public Hueco(Vector3 centro, float ancho, float alto, float largo)
{
    Centro = centro;
    hueco = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    hueco.transform.position = Centro;
    hueco.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ancho, alto, largo);
    hueco.name = "Hueco";
    hueco.tag = "Space";
    hueco.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    division = -1;


}
}
```

This is the object itself,I need to store some of the Gameobject properties of the *hueco* Gameobject and do the same with *hueco1* and *hueco2*. There are some more methods on the class but I dont think they are important here

Comment: Which objects? Please edit your question and add your current code.

Comment: It sounds like you want to serialise the object to disk, but as @KobyDouek said, this is not enoguh info to go on.

Comment: Edited with the class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Runtime Serialization for Unity. For more info, enter [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-runtime-serialization-for-unity-extremely-easy-solution-to-save-your-gameplay-data.325812/). It can serialize your c# objects to files, including Unity Objects like GameObject class.

Comment: Thank you so much, i´d heard about serialization before but I thought it only worked on GameObjects. Hope I can make it work with this.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as correct and vote for it. Thanks!